# CMake and MinGW cannot disable "is deprecated" warnings also setting CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED

Tags: cmake, mingw, warnings, deprecated, gcc-warning

I am using CMake version 3.23 with MinGW compiler

This are the basic CMAKE settings:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.23)

## GENERAL INITIALIZATION
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD          11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS        OFF)
```

I use `CMake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..` to build the project with MinGW generator and everything works. To compile I can use both `CMake --build .` or `mingw32-make.exe`: they both warks but gives the warnings that I am describing.

The problem is that I am using some external libraries (boost, turtle) that uses the `template<class> class std::auto_ptr` that is deprecated.
For this reason, when I compile my project, I get this warning:

```
C:/turtle/include/turtle/detail/action.hpp:220:22: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         mutable std::auto_ptr< Result > v_;
                      ^~~~~~~~
```

And many other of this type as well.

As I mentioned, those warnings are not a problem for compilation, but I would like to disable them.

I have tried to set CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED:

```
SET(CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED       OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

but it does not work.

I have also tried

```
add_compile_options(-Wno-deprecated-declarations)
```

but it does not work as well.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments by *Alex Reinking* CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED is not related to compilation warning but to CMAKE warning.

The only way I've found to eliminate the warnings was to redefine CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-declarations")
```

Hope it can be helpful

Comment: `CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED` is just about warnings from _CMake_ itself, not about warnings from the compiler. `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` should work... try setting it in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` at the command line and then, if you post your whole CMakeLists.txt, we can help you narrow it down.